# Preseed KeyError in cfg.jinja file while provisioning service files over FTP

Tags: python, jinja2

I cannot figure out why I am getting the KeyError on ftp when using it in the cfg file, a jinja template, (first image) and ensuring it exists when generated in a separate preseed.py file (second image). FTP is also a module in the project.
[image: The hey check and use of ftp in the cfg file (run on client)]

[image: The generated preseed template]

[image: The traceback of the error]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/runner/work/genisys/genisys/tests/modules/test_preseed.py", line 33, in test_root_password
    output = module.generate().split("\n")

             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/home/runner/work/genisys/genisys/genisys/modules/preseed.py", line 35, in generate
    return template.render(settings=self.config["users"], ftp=self.config["network"]["ftp"])
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^

KeyError: 'ftp'
```

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not a screenshot.